# Summon out of the world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command block with a `/summon` command in. When I run the command, it gives the result `Cannot summon the object out of the world`. However, when I move the command block closer to the summon location, it succeeds. Is there any way I can stop this (without moving the command block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that the command block is trying to put an entity into an unloaded chunk. The only possible solution is to run the command when the player gets near the summon location.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the chunks to load by using the `/spreadplayers` command to move an 'anchor' entity to that location first before summoning.

1. Summoning the anchor.

   ```
   /summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["anchor"]}
   ```
2. Spreading that anchor near the location.

   ```
   /spreadplayers X Z 0 1 false @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=anchor]
   ```
3. Summoning the mob.

   ```
   /summon Villager X Y Z
   ```

Alternatively you could summon the mob at the spawn chunks, spread it to the desired location, and use a `/tp` command to reposition it correctly. However, if the chunks are already loaded by the player, that spread entity may not render immediately.